# Updating thousands of records with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been given a spreadsheet in the format of :

```
Id | Val
1     57
2     99
```

There's approximately 10,000 records - Any ideas to handle the query below for 10,000 records without manually writing each case statement, tediously. Thanks.

```
  update person
  SET val = (
                   case 
                   when Id = 1 then 57
                   when Id = 2 then 99
                   end),
  where Id in (1, 2)
```

Comment: Load the data into a table and use `join`.

Comment: In the spreadsheet add another column with `="UPDATE person SET val="&B1&" WHERE Id="&A1` and use drag-to-fill.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty? here you go

Add a new spredsheet call the old one datatable
In the first row first column you write
"Update person set val = ("
in the second column you link to the value on datatable spreadsheet
third column ") where ID = ("
fourth column you link to the ID of the datatable spreadsheet
fifth column ")"
Then you mark the whole row and pull it downwards to row 10000
Copy past into query escecute

[image]

Comment: This is something I often end up with, too. When given a list, then create your statements with Excel. I find nothing dirty about this method. Simple and straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think this example can be help you :

```
CREATE TABLE #Person  
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   ValueSome      varchar(50) 
  );  
GO  

CREATE TABLE #MySpreadSheet 
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   ValueSpread      varchar(50) 
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #Person 
SELECT 1, 'someValue'

INSERT INTO #Person 
SELECT 2, 'someValueBeforeUpdate'


INSERT INTO #Person 
SELECT 3, ''

INSERT INTO #MySpreadSheet 
SELECT 1, '45'

INSERT INTO #MySpreadSheet 
SELECT 2, '56'


INSERT INTO #MySpreadSheet 
SELECT 3, '34'


SELECT * FROM #Person

SELECT * FROM #MySpreadSheet

UPDATE P SET P.ValueSome = SS.ValueSpread FROM #Person P JOIN #MySpreadSheet SS ON P.PrimaryKey = SS.PrimaryKey


SELECT * FROM #Person



DROP TABLE  #Person

DROP TABLE  #MySpreadSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyones interested, I went with this :

```
  CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
  Id int,
  val int
  )

  INSERT INTO #TempTable (Id, val)
  Values (1, 57),                       
         (2, 99)                                                                        

  Update Person
  Set Id = tp.Id,
  val = tp.val
  FROM Person p
  INNER JOIN #TempTable as tp on tp.Id = p.Id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    create table #example (id int , value int)

    insert into #example (id, value) values (1, 10)
    insert into #example (id, value) values (2, 20)

    select * from #example

    id  value
    1   10
    2   20

    update #example
    set value = case    when id = 1 then 100 
                when id = 2 then 200 end
    where id in (1,2)

    select * from #example 

    id  value
    1   100
    2   200
```

Comment: Hey read the question properly bro, he wants to avoid the case statement ,as we can't write case condtion for 10000 records right !